# Python Flask - oserror errno 22 invalid argument

Tags: python, flask, port

I have developed a UI with Python flask. By default it is running on port 5000. The home page of UI shows "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" . But when I run on the other port it is working fine, the home page of UI looks great.

What might be issue on default port 5000? I have searched around internet, most of the solution suggested to change the file path with \\ (double slash) in open() function. But I am not using anything of such kind. Can you please shed some light?

Comment: Default port `5000` might already be in use somewhere else. So running your Flask app on some other port might solve it.

Comment: Try: `sudo netstat -anp | grep ':5000 '` to check what process holds the port 5000

Comment: @vinzee Thanks. Found the process that is already running on 5000 and killed it. Now it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The port 5000 is being used by another process. To check what process holds the port 5000, do:

```sh
sudo netstat -anp | grep ':5000 '
```

and kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

it seams that your `port 5000` have a another process. so you can changing your port in a script for ruining the application. in last line of your code add "port" Variable like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```